# Reduce array of objects to string array based on boolean property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to reduce an array of objects to a string array based on a boolean property.

My object array looks like that:

```
diet: [ { slug: "dairy-free", selected: true, }, { slug: "fish", selected: false, }, { slug: "meat", selected: false, }, { slug: "poultry", selected: true, }, { slug: "vegetarian", selected: true, }, ]
```

My ideal outcome would be a string array if the **selected** value is true.

```
["dairy-free", "poultry", "vegetarian"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` method to filter the records which have **selected** value as true. This will return an array of objects that satisfy the condition

```js
var diet = [ { slug: "dairy-free", selected: true, }, { slug: "fish", selected: false, }, { slug: "meat", selected: false, }, { slug: "poultry", selected: true, }, { slug: "vegetarian", selected: true, }, ]

console.log(diet.filter(e => e.selected))
```

If you want to return only the **slug** property, you can use `filter` and `map` methods combined

```js
var diet = [ { slug: "dairy-free", selected: true, }, { slug: "fish", selected: false, }, { slug: "meat", selected: false, }, { slug: "poultry", selected: true, }, { slug: "vegetarian", selected: true, }, ]

    console.log(diet.filter(e => e.selected == true).map(e => e.slug))
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need `filter` and `map`.

Using `filter` you will get those whose value `selected` is true. And `map` is for mapping `slug` value for these objects into an array.

```js
var diet = [ { slug: "dairy-free", selected: true, }, { slug: "fish", selected: false, }, { slug: "meat", selected: false, }, { slug: "poultry", selected: true, }, { slug: "vegetarian", selected: true, }, ]

var newArray = diet.filter(f => f.selected).map(m => m.slug)
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this using a combination of `Array` functions `filter` and `map`:

```js
let diet= [ { slug: "dairy-free", selected: true, }, { slug: "fish", selected: false, }, { slug: "meat", selected: false, }, { slug: "poultry", selected: true, }, { slug: "vegetarian", selected: true, }, ]

let selected=diet.filter(type=>type.selected).map(selectedType=>selectedType.slug)
console.log(selected)
```

This unfortunately requires two iterations over an array, once to filter out the `selected` and once to return only the `slug`

You can also achieve the same result using `reduce` like this

```js
let diet= [ { slug: "dairy-free", selected: true, }, { slug: "fish", selected: false, }, { slug: "meat", selected: false, }, { slug: "poultry", selected: true, }, { slug: "vegetarian", selected: true, }, ]

let reduced = diet.reduce((filtered, option)=> {
  if (option.selected) {
     filtered.push(option.slug);
  }
  return filtered;
}, []);

console.log(reduced)
```

`reduce` would be the recommended approach since you only iterate once over the array

Answer (score 0):

**another way could be**

```
final newList = diet.fold<List>([], (previousValue, e) {
      if (e["selected"]) {
        previousValue.add(e["slug"]);
      }
      return previousValue;
    });
```